# Drag and Drop Control

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#div1
{float:left; width:100px; height:35px; margin:10px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}

 #div2
{float:left; width:200px; height:100px; margin:10px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}

</style>
<script>

function allowDrop(ev)
{
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    document.getElementById(data).width="200"
    document.getElementById(data).height="100"
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="f1" name="form1" method="post">
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <img src="smiley.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="31"></div>
    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Clear" >
</form>
</body>
```

In this code when i drop the image i need to delete the image from div2 when i click the clear button.How to write javascript code for this issue . onclick function to code i have to write . please help me

Comment: Bahrgavi, Check my latest answer. It has a code for an **improved presentation**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple. Use the following code-

```
<input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML='';">
```

in place of-

```
<input type="button" value="Clear">
```

For **further improvement of presentation** use the following code-

```
<input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="if(document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML!='')document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML=document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML; document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML=''">
```

Giving here a **[fiddle_solution](http://jsfiddle.net/HFKhE/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

try this: [**LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/HFKhE/1/)

```
function allowDrop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

Comment: hi Thanks for ur reply . i think u wrongly understand my question . in drag and drop i need to clear the image when i drop to div2 . please tell me